# Create array of active record association Rails4

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have posts that are associated with comments. I want to create an array of comments from the first 10 posts. I had the following method but to_a seems to not work anymore? Also will this give an N+1 query? should I do `includes(:comments)` to preload them?

```
def 10_posts_comments
  posts = Post.limit(10)

  posts.flat_map do |post|
    post.comments.to_a
  end

end
```

I'm still new at this so any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
def 10_posts_comments     
  Comment.where(post: Post.limit(10)).to_a
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
def latest_comments
  Post.includes(:comments).last(10).map(&:comments).flatten
end
```

Comment: You can use your method, I just changed the name since it bothered me the leading 10. Sorry.